# How to manage different css style for different layouts in react Js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two different layouts for front End and for admin End.I am including css files in render function in both layouts but css conflicts in both layouts.

Layout for front End

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Switch, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "components/FrontEnd/Header/Header";
import Footer from "components/FrontEnd/Footer/Footer";
import Menu from "components/FrontEnd/Menu/Menu";

class Frontend extends Component {
  render() {
    require("../../assets/fonts/frontEnd.css");
    return (
      <div className="section-frontEnd">
        <Header {...this.props} />
        <div id="main-panel" className="" ref="mainPanel">
          <Switch>
            //Routes Swichting ...
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Frontend;
```

Layout for Admin End

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {  Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "components/Admin/Header/Header";
import Footer from "components/Admin/Footer/Footer";
import Sidebar from "components/Admin/Sidebar/Sidebar";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    require('bootstrap/dist/css/Admin.css')
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Sidebar  />
        <div id="main-panel" className="main-panel" ref="mainPanel">
          <Header  />
          <Switch>
            //Routes Swichting ...
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Dashboard;
```

Please suggest me a better solution for this problem.
Note:I am not using webpack file in my project.
Below is my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each page section Make one superclass and Write all CSS based on that. This method won't conflict the layouts.

Example:

```
.section-frontEnd #main-panel{
  // code
}

.admin-frontEnd #main-panel{
  // code
}
```

Comment: yes i have done this already and with its working fine but i want to ask is this standard option in react for multi layouts?

Comment: I am following this way to maintain the CSS code properly because React generates many reuse components so that each component one main class. This way is easy to maintain the CSS for large-scale application.

Comment: hmm so do you think its better way

Comment: When I start my react project I facing many CSS Conflict issue, later I implement this logic with SCSS(Gulp automation). Now I can easily maintain my CSS code. This my suggestion from my experience.

Comment: but i didn't use SCSS i only use .css should i change this now?

Comment: Yes. SCSS is good to maintain the CSS and avoid duplication for the Large-scale application. https://github.com/rahdirs/gulp

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect}from'react';

const Admin Layout = () => {
  Use Effect(() => {
    import('./admin.css').then(() => {
      // Admin CSS has been loaded
    });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup or remove the user CSS if necessary
    };
  }, []);

  // Admin layout JSX here
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Admin layout content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminLayout;

import React, { Use Effect } from 'react';

const User Layout = () => {
  Use Effect(() => {
    import('./user.css').then(() => {
      // User CSS has been loaded
    });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup or remove the user CSS if necessary
    };
  }, []);

  // User layout JSX here
  return (
    <div>
      {/* User layout content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default User Layout;
```

Comment: You should add explanation.